# production calling api from localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, vue-cli-3

I have deployed my application (created with `npm run build`) to heroku. However, the api calls done on heroku production are from my localhost. How do I change this? Could anyone please advice?

**api_axios.js**

```
const axios = require('axios')

export default () => {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://myapp.herokuapp.com/api/' || 'http://localhost:1991/api/'
  })
}
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const port = process.env.PORT || 1991


// express app
const app = express()

// middleware
app.use(cors())

// routes
const metrics = require('./routes/api/metrics') 
app.use('/api/metrics', metrics)

// handle production
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
    // static folder
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'))

    // handle spa
    app.get(/.*/, (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html'))
}

// run server
const server = app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`server running on port ${port}`)
})
```

Comment: An `||` comparison of non-empty strings is going to always evaluate to the first string, so `'https://myapp.herokuapp.com/api/' || 'http://localhost:1991/api/'` should never evaluate to your localhost url. As such just take that out and use the correct string or setup a proper ternary or similar statement to set your url

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand your question. What do you mean by this: `the api calls done on heroku production are from my localhost`?  On the other hand, this line: `'https://myapp.herokuapp.com/api/' || 'http://localhost:1991/api/'` will always resolve to the first string.

Comment: Maybe you are using a different axios instance. `'a' || 'b'` always returns `a`

Comment: Show the actual api call , something going wri]ong there

Answer (score 1):

Just like you check `process.env.NODE_ENV` in your server, you should also check environment when you compile your JavaScript.

You can use environment variables (via `process.env` as above), configuration files (such as `require('./config.json')`, or any other method you like.  At the end of the day though, you shouldn't hardcode your API URL.

Comment: could you show me an example how `process.env` is able to check if I am on development or production? Also, how should `config.json` look like?